# Error referencing same basis texture files with Promise in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am using example  https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_standard for my purposes but can't get the code to read both metal and rough maps when using promise (Cerberus_RM metalness is in channel B roughness is in channel G):

```
Promise.all([
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( 
    "Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_A.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( 
    "Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_N.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
                    **new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( 
    "Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_RM.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),**
**                  new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( 
    "Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_RM.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),**
**                  ]).then(([albedoM, normalMap, metalMap, roughMap]) => {**
```

Yields error:

`BasisTextureLoader.js:152 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': ArrayBuffer at index 0 is already neutered.
at examples/jsm/loaders/BasisTextureLoader.js:152:13
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at examples/jsm/loaders/BasisTextureLoader.js:146:12`

I tried this code but I only get a full metal textured object without roughness (both roughness and metalness settings=1). Can I please get some guidance how to build this with Promise

```
Promise.all([
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_A.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_N.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load(Photog_Glace1/Cerberus_RM.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
            ]).then(([albedoM, normalMap, metalMap, roughMap]) => {
            albedoM.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                                albedoM.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                                albedoM.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            albedoM.repeat.x = 1;
                                albedoM.repeat.y = 1;

            normalMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                                normalMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                                normalMap.repeat.x = 1;
                                normalMap.repeat.y = 1;

            metalMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                                metalMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                                metalMap.repeat.x = 1;
                                metalMap.repeat.y = 1;
            roughMap=metalMap;

             vaseMeshMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                    roughnessMap: roughMap,
                    metalnessMap: metalMap,
                    map: albedoM,
                    normalMap: normalMap,
                    roughness: settings.roughness,
                    metalness: settings.metalness,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    });

                    roughMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                    roughMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                    roughMap.repeat.x = 1;
                    roughMap.repeat.y = 1;
```

in case three.js forum would become unavailable solution was:

```html
Promise.all([
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/albedo.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/normal.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/cavity.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => basisLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/rough_metal_Map.basis", resolve, undefined, reject ) ),
      ]).then(([albedoM, normalMap, aoMap, metalRoughMap]) => {

     albedoM.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
       
     vaseMeshMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      roughnessMap: metalRoughMap,
      metalnessMap: metalRoughMap,
      map: albedoM,
      normalMap: normalMap,
      roughness: settings.roughness,
      metalness: settings.metalness,
      aoMap: aoMap,
      aoMapIntensity: 1,
      flatShading: false,
     
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
     });
     
        console.log("Materials Finished Loading");
     myObjectLoader.load( "Photog_Glace1/Glace1_Model.obj", function ( group ) {
      var geometry = group.children[ 0 ].geometry;
      geometry.attributes.uv2 = geometry.attributes.uv;
      geometry.center();

      vaseMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, vaseMeshMaterial );
      vaseMeshMaterial.normalScale.x = -1;
      vaseMesh.castShadow = true;
      vaseMesh.receiveShadow = true;
      vaseMesh.position.set(28,0,0);
     } , onProgress,onError);
    });
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example using Stack Snippets. You can link a copy of three.js from cdnjs. With a snippet, we'll not only be able to see how you're configuring everything, but also see what you're seeing in the rendered scene.

Comment: Hi @TheJim01 I tested with the webgl_materials_standard three.js example and it seems the problem is I can't read same texture file for different material properties - I use promise because I use basis textures. How would this be correctly coded to reference same texture file for both metal/rough properties?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was basis loader won't read the same file more than once, e.g. metallic in B channel and rough in G channel. I couldn't get the right code using Promise. Thanks to @Mugen87 and @donmccurdy who helped solved the issue, full thread on Three.js forum https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-part-rough-part-specular/9985/8

Comment: Could you please post the gist of the solution here in your answer? I don't expect the three.js forum to go down any time soon, but external links can even change over time, and the context of your solution could be lost.